# SQL syntax which sending me an Error

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, server-error

I have a Mysql Database named user. Here is a picture:
[image]

I want to change the Username of the user "dodlo.rg" programmatically.

Actually, I have the PHP-Version 7.1. And this is a part of my PHPCode:

**EDITED CODE:**

```
$newName= $_POST["changeT"];  
$userId = $_POST["userId"];

      $db = mysqli_connect("trolö", "trolö", "trolö123", "trolö")
      $sql = "UPDATE user SET username = '$newName' WHERE user_id = '$userId'";
      $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
      $response["successU"] = true;
```

But I get the Error: "You gave an Error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM user' at line 1"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need this ` SELECT * FROM user`

Comment: Also, make it a habit of using the 'user_id' as a reference for updating instead of the username. in a case of duplicates.

Comment: @hungrykoala Should I do it with the user_id even when every username can be only taken by one person?

Comment: Yes for best practice. Especially if you are using sessions

Comment: Make sure to properly sanitize/escape your `$newName`, you're leaving a big hole for SQL injections here.

Comment: @hungrykoala Can you please look at my edited Code in my Question, because when I try it with the user_id it doesn't work.

Comment: user_id or ids, in general, are usually stored in sessions after the user logs in the system. Does neglecting the need to pass them as a post parameter since you can just access them via the session variable. in your case try to print your `$userId` to see what value it holds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in 2 parts.
Firstly, since this column is a varchar field it needs to be inside quotes else it produces an sql error.
Secondly the SELECT statement just after is not valid, but i guess it was a copy/paste error.

Therefore your working code should be:

```
$newName= $_POST["changeT"];  

  $db = mysqli_connect("trolö", "trolö", "trolö123", "trolö")
  $sql = "UPDATE user SET username = '".addslashes($newName)."' WHERE username = 'dodlo.rg'";
  $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  $response["successU"] = true;
```

Also, please consider using your primary keys on your where statement rather a varchar field, as it'll improve speed when more complex queries. (eg. `where user_id = 35 instead of where username = 'dodlo.rg'` ).

Lastly, but quite important this code might be vulnerable to sql injections. You need to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert this query into two parts

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE user SET username = $newName WHERE username = 'dodlo.rg'";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user";
```